# narcissism and cognition

Tags: personality-disorder

Is there a tight coupling between narcissism and certain forms of cognitive impairment? Does this vary by vulnerable vs. grandiose narcissism ?

People I've known formally diagnosed with a cluster B personality disorder frequently have trouble with abstract problem solving. They aren't unintelligent, some even have PhDs, but they have anomalously poor performance in high school math on up. The more abstract the problem the worse their performance.

This has me wondering if part of the empathy problem associated with narcissism has less to do with not caring about others than a fundamental failure to understand them in a complex way.